# Why are some apps not showing up in the list in iTunes?

Tags: ios, itunes, ios-appstore

I want to manage my iPhone apps via iTunes. There are a few things getting in my way:

1. the main thing is that some apps don't show up in the list, as shown in the screenshot. There is an app named "Via" which is on my iPhone and is seen in the visual list to the right (not in the screenshot). So if I want to organize those apps, I have to hunt around for them.
2. another mystery is that there are many apps shown in the list and in the visual view which are not currently on my phone. these are apps i downloaded in the distant past. they are not currently on my phone, but for some reason show up in the visual view.

How can I get everything up to date?

[image: screenshot of itunes showing a search for an app which is on the phone but doesn't come up in the list]

Comment: Is your device jailbroken? Do you have IconSupport installed?

Comment: My device is not jailbroken. I don't know what iconsupport is.